# How to solve the exponential equation $e^{a+bx}+e^{c+dx}=1$?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, roots

$$e^{a+bx}+e^{c+dx}=1$$
The problem comes from formula (14) in [this paper](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~chum/papers/chum-pami08.pdf), which says the solution is found numerically. My questions are:

1. Does there exist an analytical solution?
2. How to derive the numerical solution?

PS. My post tags might be inaccurate and false, but I am sorry that I cannot figure out proper tags, someone may fix it.

**EDIT**  I found [C++ program](https://github.com/cr333/usac-cmake/blob/master/src/estimators/USAC.h)(line 1002, function *computeExpSPRT*) solving the equation in paper, now rewrite the equation as
$$ \exp(\log \epsilon+h\log \frac{\delta_i}{\epsilon_i})+\exp(\log (1-\epsilon)+h\log \frac{1-\delta_i}{1-\epsilon_i})=1$$
$\epsilon,\delta_i,\epsilon_i$ are known and lie in $(0,1)$ and $\epsilon \ge \epsilon_i$, now the target is to search a $h$ satisfying above equation with $h>1$. According to the program, $h$ can be numerically found as follows:
$$al=\log(\frac{\delta_i}{\epsilon_i}),be=\log \frac{1-\delta_i}{1-\epsilon_i}$$
$$x_0=-\frac{1}{be}\log(1-\epsilon),v_0=\epsilon\exp (al\cdot x_0)$$
$$x_1=\frac{1}{be}\log{\frac{1-2v_0}{1-\epsilon}},v_1=\epsilon \exp(al \cdot x_1)+(1-\epsilon)\exp(be \cdot x_1)$$
$$h=\frac{1-v_1}{1+v_0-v_1}x_0+\frac{v_0}{1+v_0-v_1}x_1$$
Can anyone help me analyzing the thread?

Comment: This boils down to polynomial root finding if $\frac{d}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Provided a "reasonable" guess of the solution, Newton method is the candidate.

Comment: Any numerical analysis text will have a whole chapter on one-dimensional root finding.  Any of the techniques will work on this problem.  The [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) is probably the easiest to understand.  It takes more evaluations of the function than others for the precision achieved, but when the function is easy it is easier to get going than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the more specific case of
$$f(x)=a\,e^{bx}+(1-a)\,e^{cx}-1$$ where $0<a<1$, we have
$$f'(x)=a b\, e^{b x}+(1-a) c\, e^{c x}$$
$$f''(x)=a b^2 \,e^{b x}+(1-a) c^2\, e^{c x}\, >0 \qquad \forall x$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$x_{min}=\frac{\log \left(\frac{-(1-a) c}{a b}\right)}{b-c}$$ which, in the real domain exists if $bc<0$ and this is a minimum and, since $f(0)=0$, the solution of $f(x)=0$ is away from $x_{min}$.

Since $f(x_{min}) <0$, we need to find a value  $x_*$ such that $f(x_*)>0$ in order to start Newton iterations and this would be safe (no overshoot of the solution since at this point $f(x_*)\,f''(x_*)>0$ - by Draboux theorem).

To find this point, we could use a golden search that is to say define a sequence
$$x_k=\phi^k \,x_{min}$$ (where $\phi$ is the golden ratio) and run it until $f(x_k)>0$. If you prefer, replace $\phi$ by any number $>1$.

For example, using $a=0.123$, $b=0.234$, $c=-0.345$, we get $x_{min}=4.06312$. So 
$$x_1=6.57426\implies f(x_1)=-0.336410$$
$$x_2=10.6374\implies f(x_2)=+0.504618$$ Now, Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_{(n)} \\
 0 & 10.63738381 \\
 1 & 9.149460984 \\
 2 & 8.788301285 \\
 3 & 8.769596643 \\
 4 & 8.769548495
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Comment: It seems that this nonzero root must be greater than 1, I can not yet proven that, can you help?

Comment: I have encoded the problem with Newton method, it worked out the same results as the author's program, so fantastic. But the author didn't use iterative method.

Comment: @Finley. In the linked paper, about $(14)$, the authors write *"This solution is found numerically"*. If they *didn't use iterative method*, it means an explicit solution what I do not think feasible. Could you clarify this point ?

Comment: just described in this post's **EDIT**, in this [page](https://github.com/cr333/usac-cmake/blob/master/src/estimators/USAC.h) a function programmed by C++(line 1002, named computeExpSPRT) is used to compute the root of (14) and the computation thread is described in my **EDIT**. But the iterative method seems not used.

Comment: I have checked this function, it generated the same results as the iterative method that you proposed. So fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Writing th problem as $$e^{a+bx}+e^{c+dx}=1$$ is a generalization of equation $(14)$ in the linked paper in which they have $e^a+e^c=1$.

For sure, we shall assume $b\neq d$ (otherwise, the problem would be very simple).

So, let us consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=e^a \, e^{bx}+e^c \, e^{dx}-1\tag 1$$ If the function does not go through any extremum, it is bounded by
$$g(x)=(e^a+e^c)\,e^{bx}-1\implies x_1=-\frac{\log \left(e^a+e^c\right)}{b}\tag 2$$
$$h(x)=(e^a+e^c)\,e^{dx}-1\implies x_2=-\frac{\log \left(e^a+e^c\right)}{d}\tag 3$$ and then, the solution $x_*$ of $(1)$ is such that 
$$\min (x_1,x_2) < x_* <\max (x_1,x_2)$$ On the other hand
$$f'(x)=b\ e^{a+b x}+d\, e^{c+d x}$$ **may** cancel at
$$x_3=\frac{c-\log \left(-\frac{ b}{d}e^a\right)}{b-d}$$ which can only happen if $b\,d<0$.

If $x_3$ does exist, it would correspond to a minimum of the function since
$$f''(x)=b^2\ e^{a+b x}+d^2\, e^{c+d x} >0$$ and, if $f(x_3)<0$, we should find $\color{red}{\text{two}}$ solutions (one being $< x_3$ and one being $> x_3$). But, if $f(x_3)>0$, $\color{red}{\text{no}}$ solution to the equation.

If $x_3$ does not exist in the real domain, then no minimum and you can start Newton method using 
$$x_0=\frac{x_1+x_2}2$$ to find the  $\color{red}{\text{single}}$ root of the equation.

For illustration purposes, let us consider the case $a=0.123$, $b=0.234$, $c=0.345$, $d=0.456$. Since $b\,d >0$, $x_3$ does not exist and we have $x_1\approx-3.98844$ and $x_2\approx -2.04670$. So, let us start Newton method using $x_0=-3$. The iterates would then be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -3.000000000 \\
 1 & -2.728802219 \\
 2 & -2.741157913 \\
 3 & -2.741185518
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Using the same numbers except $b=-0.234$ we have $x_1\approx 3.98844$, $x_2\approx -2.04670$ and $x_3 \approx -1.28865$ but $f(x_3) \approx 1.31346$; then no root.

Finally, consider the case $a=-0.789$, $b=-0.123$, $c=-0.345$, $d=0.456$. For these values, $x_1\approx 1.22430$, $x_2\approx -0.330240$ and $x_3 \approx -3.02989$ and $f(x_3) \approx-0.16265$; so, two roots. 
So, Newton iterates would then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -0.6085273172 \\
 2 & -0.7506361354 \\
 3 & -0.7576454727 \\
 4 & -0.7576619221 \\
 5 & -0.7576619222
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, for the second

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -5.000000000 \\
 1 & -6.240875927 \\
 2 & -6.044184300 \\
 3 & -6.039496855
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: According to equation(14) in paper, $bd=\log \frac{\delta_i}{\epsilon_i} \cdot \log \frac{1-\delta_i}{1-\epsilon_i} < 0 \text{ for } \delta_i,\epsilon_i \text{ lying in } (0,1)$ , so I think your theory applies :)

Comment: @Finley. You asked for a more general problem as I wrote at the start of my answer. If you are concerned by $a e^{bx}+(1-a)e^{cx}=1$, let me know.

Comment: yeah, I actually want to know the way solving $ae^{bx}+(1-a)e^{cx}=1$ first.

Comment: @Finley. Any restriction on $a,b,c$ ? Please precise if any is $>0$ or $<0$  or $<1$ or $<1$ or whatever. Again, solving $(14)$ was not the question (at least in title). Cheers.

Comment: Well, please solve (14) first where $a \in (0,1);c,d \in \Bbb R$. Thanks! :),